# how can we wrap the text into some size then display dots in sencha touch html

Tags: html, sencha-touch, extjs

i am displaying some text in a table view with html code,in that i have a text value which is exceeding screen,so i want to wrap up that text to some fixed size it it exceeds that size i want to show some dots appending to that,
how can i do this in html.
my code for that is

```
html:' <table class=manager><tr><td width=99%>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.com</td></tr></table>'
```

in the above text i want to display upto 'q',then onwards some dots i want to display,
like this

```
abcdefghijklmnopq..
```

for that what i have to do

Comment: This is exactly the reason why I didn't answer this simple question.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is what you were trying to do, but take a look and decide:

```
.manager{
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100px;
 }

.manager td {
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
 }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9TF7f/1/